# NSpredicate "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath SELF.SIZE not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Files id=1>'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a problem I can't figure out so I'm hoping in some help :)

I have a dore data db with the metadata of a filesystem. I want to retrieve the number of files > 10 kbytes, so I'm using a predicate statement. Unfortunately the app crashes with:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath SELF.SIZE not found in entity '

Here the code:

```
// Initialize NSFetchrequest and define entity

NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *file = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Files" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:file];

// Query on Number of files between 0 and 10000 bytes

NSNumber * tenk = @10000;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any self.size < %@", tenk];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
fetchResult = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request  error:&error];

int primaBar = fetchResult.count;
NSLog(@"Files smaller than 10k: %d :",primaBar);
```

The code works if instead of comparing NSnumbers I compare strings (e.g. I'm able to retrieve the number of files with extension "pdf" with the predicate @"any self.extension contains %@",extension ) so I believe that I'm doing something wrong accessing the NSnumber self.size.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

dom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistery Solved.

-From the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

...all the way to the bottom you can read:

/*

Reserved Words

The following words are reserved:

AND, OR, IN, NOT, ALL, ANY, SOME, NONE, LIKE, CASEINSENSITIVE, CI, MATCHES, CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH, BETWEEN, NULL, NIL, SELF, TRUE, YES, FALSE, NO, FIRST, LAST, SIZE, ANYKEY, SUBQUERY, CAST, TRUEPREDICATE, FALSEPREDICATE

.
*/

You can see that size is a reserved work, and this did interfere with the execution of the predicate.

At the end escaping it with ' ' like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any self.'size' < %@" , tenk];
```

made my query work.

I'm new to IOS programming, but this was a tricky one (learning to code in the hardest way...).

Thanks for the brainstorming !

dom

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is syntax.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K < %@",
        attributeName, attributeValue];
```

So you can Try this.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K < %@",@"\size" ,tenk];
```

I think, Here `size` is attribute name.

**Update:**

see [Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) concept. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks: it does not recognize "size" as attribute. Tried self.size and file.size ['file' is the entity name] but still not able to recognize it so compiling fails.

Comment: @user3130919 Did you have attribute name with `size` in your entity?

Comment: yes, and did not know that size is a reserved word, hence the crash

Comment: Using `%K` here is a good solution because "size" is a reserved keyword in predicates. The only error that you made is that is should be `@"size"`, not `@"\size"`.

Comment: well even "NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any self.size < %@", tenk];" is a good solution except for the fact that size is a reserved word so I had to escape it. I found out reading the documentation.

Comment: no, the correct solution is: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any self.'size' < %@" , tenk];

Answer (score 1):

SELF refers to the current object being used.

use this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"size < %@", tenk];
```

Note: this works only if there is a database attribute named size which stores the size of each file.

Comment: Thanks. size is one of the attributes of the entity "Files" so we are good there. Without self i have this error: "** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported expression type (11, SIZE)'" . The issue is related to the fact that size is a NSnumber as whatever other query with an attribute that is a string works fine (using self). Not sure what is the effect of a NSnumber on a predicate, so I am kind of stuck.

Comment: SIZE is actually a reserved word. See the list of reserved words in [NSPredicate reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-213522)
Other than that you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

try `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"size < %@", tenk];`